# Multiple Images in background showing Invalid Property Value Error

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Check my website out - http://icestartup.com/testsites/site2/

The background is supposed to be a layer of 2 images and a background color. But when I did that it is showing a "invalid property error" in Chrome inspector.

This is the code I used:

```
body {
 background: url(http://icestartup.com/testsites/site2/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/gradient.png) no-repeat  scroll center top transparent, url(http://icestartup.com/testsites/site2/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/background-pattern.png) repeat scroll transparent, #90B601;
}
```

To see the exact error I have uploaded a screenshot - The error can be seen in the Chrome inspector in this image

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: On your post it says you used the `background`property but on the screenshot it says you used `background-color`

Comment: thats the old screenshot. I changed that. You can see the website again - http://icestartup.com/testsites/site2/ and try inspect. You will see the error again.

Comment: Sorry man, can't help at this moment because I'm on mobile... No inspection

Comment: Do you want me to send a new screenshot?

Comment: You could try, but the error is pretty obvious, there is something wrong with the property, possibly because it's not supported by the html element or the property has some invalid attribute.

Comment: http://i65.tinypic.com/102l2di.png - Here you go. The code used is not clear in the image but  you can see that I have used background, not background - color. The actual code i used is what is given in the question.

Comment: Yeah, but no matter how hard i tried i cant find the property error. It looks like it is correct. You can see the property clearly in this link - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

Comment: It should be correct because before, you only used background-color, but background should encompass all the attributes so I'll keep on looking

Comment: Thanks. Please try to figure it out. I am almost about to give up here. Haha

Comment: No whitespace is allowed in css.

Comment: @Adam Please check my answer below..

Comment: @AndrewL Sunil solved the problem. Check the answer out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `transparent` from your code as it is creating issue..

Please use below Code:

```
body{
    background:url(http://www.icestartup.com/testsites/site2/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/gradient.png) no-repeat top center, url(http://www.icestartup.com/testsites/site2/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/background-pattern.png) repeat, #90B601;
}
```

Comment: Dude you are awesome. That FIXED IT!

Comment: Do you have a blog, website or something? I will follow you

Comment: You can find me here and happy that i helped you :)

Comment: @Adam if this helps you, kindly accept as answer. Thank You :)

Comment: Just did that. Thank you.

Comment: How did you know transparent is creating issue? Can you tell me some good way to debug CSS?

Comment: Wow, I didn't see that! Good answer

Comment: @AndrewL Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in your code is with the color attribute. This is the correct syntax for the css3 background tag for multiple images:

```
background: [ <bg-layer> , ]* <final-bg-layer>

<bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <bg-position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box>{1,2} 

<final-bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <bg-position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box>{1,2} || <background-color>
```

Please note that `background-color` is only permitted in the final background layer ([1](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)).

You should whether use something like this:

```
background: url(http://icestartup.com/testsites/site2/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/gradient.png) no-repeat scroll center top, url(http://icestartup.com/testsites/site2/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/background-pattern.png) repeat scroll transparent
```

Or use separate background-image tags as you find in the examples in the link attached above.